# Actionscript duplicate variable definition

Tags: actionscript-3, scope

```
if(true) {
  var a:int = 1;
}
else {
  var a:int = 2;
}
```

In the above actionscript code I get duplicate variable definition
error because "a" has been declared twice.
But, doesn't "a" exist in two "different" scopes?

Is there an elegant way of removing this warning, rather
than pulling "a" out of both the scopes and moving it outside
the if block?

I need that alternate solution since it is in just too many places
in a code which I have to refactor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yup, all you need to do is

```
if(true) {
  var a:int = 1;
}else {
  a= 2;
}
```

and your error will be gone

Answer (score 4):

No, as JavaScript, ActionScript has only one possible scope - function. `{}` does not create new scope, only `function() {}` does.

Answer (score 0):

There is no elegant solution, other than pulling out the variable or the second time just referencing the variable, not declaring it.

Check out this answer as well:

[want to remove warnings:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316605/want-to-remove-warnings)

Answer (score 0):

You should always declare your variables before calling them within the function, always a safer way to code without running into duplication errors.

```
var a:int;

if(true) {
  a= 1;
}
else {
  a= 2;
}
```

Good Luck