# want to remove warnings:

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am facing a problem as Duplicate variable definition while compiling but it is not at all effecting my program.

Is there any way to remove compiler errors beacause it is coming every time when i run movie.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the duplicate variable definition. I suspect that you are doing something like the following:

```
function foo() : void {
    for(var i:uint=0; i<10; i++) {
        // do stuff in here
    } 
    for(var i:uint=0; i<10; i++) {
        // do stuff in here
    }
}
```

This will complain about duplicate variable definitions at compilation because you've got two definitions of i. During compilation, actionscript does what's called "variable hoisting". It means that all variables declarations are moved to the top of the function. (I don't know exactly why it does this) If you make the second loop look like the following, the warning will go away:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try from the Edit menu Preferences/Warnings and check off those warnings that you don't want to see.

Comment: This is generally considered bad practice. Fix the problem, don't hide it. It will likely come back to haunt you later.

Comment: I totally agree, but he wanted a "way to remove compiler errors" which are not affecting the code, but again, I agree with your comment.

Comment: Thanks for reply. By the way i am she.
Actually i am using, case statment, in which all variables are storing in another variable (var term) in each case. I m doing because i want to write function with argument of this variable "term ".
Am I in wrong way???

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your scenario without the actual code segment, but like @ablerman said, get lost of all the var keywords, except from the first instance of the given variable (term) declaration, and you should end up without those warnings.